# Equivalent of "@section" in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In the default `_Layout.cshtml` file, scripts are defined in "environment"s like so:

```
<environment names="Development">
     <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
     <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
     <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery">
     </script>
     <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal">
     </script>
     <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```

And below that is `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`

I can't seem to implement a section (in this case "scripts") in any separate .cshtml file since it looks like they got rid of "`@section`" in Core

I would like to add specific scripts for specific views. What is the new way to go about this? Do I just dump everything in `_Layout` now?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I think you are mistaken. It works just fine in ASP.NET Core. I have this in my _layout.cshtml

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

and in one of my views I'm adding scripts there like this:

```
@section Scripts {
    @if (Model.CanEdit)
   {
      await Html.RenderPartialAsync("EditorScriptsPartial");
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow you are completely right - that was my silly mistake. I wasn't seeing "@section" popping up in intellisense and instead was seeing different section functions which threw me off. Thank you very much, Joe. I'll mark this is as the answer when I'm able to.

Comment: Also, I have another quick question - maybe you could help out. In _Layout, does it matter in which environment (Development, Staging, etc.) I put my scripts?

Comment: typically in development you would add the unminified scripts whereas in production you would have minified scripts and/or scripts that you bundle together. So yes it matters if you use environment tags to wrap them but it is optional whether you wrap scripts in environment.

Comment: Is this uppercase / lowercase required, I wonder? "scripts", "Scripts"

Comment: yes it does, any section works as long as the section is defined in layout. nothing special about styles section