# How to inject page specific js into _Layout

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working with .NET Core 2.0 MVC. If I wanted to have different js files for different pages, how would I inject this js reference from the Login page, for example, into the bottom of the Shared/_Layout page under the other scripts when the Login page is loaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of "@section" in ASP.NET Core MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222224/equivalent-of-section-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Razor views/layouts can be nested and sections rendered into placeholders.

So in the main top level layout you could have

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
```

and on the pages have (with deployment options):

```
@section Scripts {

    <environment names="Development">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/Home/yourpagescript.js")" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/Home/yourpagescript.min.js")" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
}
```

Comment: do we know if the `Scripts` keyword is case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

In Shared/_Layout :

```
@RenderSection("scripts", false) //where you need your script
```

In a page:

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>

}
```